# Как указать файл json из папки assests для Retrofit

Tags: android

Подскажите пожалуйста как указать файл json из папки assests для Retrofit?  Сейчас у меня файл json берется с удаленного сайта так

SiteController

```
public class SiteController {
    private static final String BASE_URL = "https://site.ru";

    private static Retrofit getRetrofirInstance() {
        return new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE_URL).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
    }

    public static SiteAPI getSiteAPI() {
        return getRetrofirInstance().create(SiteAPI.class);
    }
}
```

Интерфейс SiteAPI

```
public interface SiteAPI {
    @GET("/for_android/info.json")
    Call<ItemList> getInfo();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Библиотека Retrofit используется для сетевых запросов. Для чтения локальных данных она не нужно. Достаточно только json парсера Gson.

Читаем файл из assets и парсим его в объект с помощью Gson:

```
try {

    InputStream json = getAssets().open("content.json");
    ItemList itemList = new Gson()
            .fromJson(new InputStreamReader(json, "UTF-8"), ItemList.class);

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```